# Scipy Ttest_ind and Ranksum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to perform tow sample t test. My data set consists of 744 rows and 186 columns for which I have calculated total sum and mean. I need to perform two sample t test. My csv looks like this from which I have to calculate ttest and rank sum test for each row as individual row denotes separate ID and have the corresponding values :

```
SRA ID  ERR169499            ERR169498           ERR169497
Label   1                    0                   1
TaxID   PRJEB3251_ERR169499  PRJEB3251_ERR169499 PRJEB3251_ERR169499
333046  0.05                 0.99                99.61
1049    0.03                 2.34                34.33
337090  0.01                 9.78                23.22
99007   22.33                2.90                0.00
```

The labels 0 and 1 are for case and control respectively.I have to calculate ttest for case columns vs ctrl columns.

```
df = pd.read_csv('final_out_transposed.csv')
for row in df.iterrows():
  (tt_val, p_ttest) = ttest_ind(df.sum_case, df.sum_ctrl)
  (tr_val, p_ranksum) = ranksums(df.sum_case, df.sum_ctrl)
  print (tt_val)
  print (p_ttest)
  print (tr_val)
  print (p_ranksum)
```

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: can you provide the full traceback? The error is that you're trying to use a 1D array as a multiple dimensional array

Comment: Check what `df1` and `df2` are. I'm pretty sure they are scalar boolean values (as returned by `.any()`) and no dataframes, as you seem to expect.

Comment: @Usernamenotfound I have edited the question. Kindly take a look.

Comment: @kazemakase if I remove them im getting all the values as NaN. After that line when Im printing those dataframes Im gettinn the values and also     `print(data_frame1['case'].dtypes` are giving `float64`

Comment: This line `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'case':['sum_case']}).isnull().values.any()` and this line `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'control':['sum_ctrl']}).isnull().values.any()` only produces the value `False`. Which causes `(t_stat, p) = ttest_ind(df2['control'], df1['case'])` to return your error.

Comment: @IanThompson if im removing those im getting the values NaN. Any idea how to remove `.isnull().values.any()` and proceed with t test ?

Comment: They are NaN because you are making an empty dataframe. Do this instead `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'case': dataframe.sum_case})` and similar for `df2`

Comment: @kazemakase sorry for the earlier comment I tried running it again and I got the same error. I guess the problem is with dataframes. Any idea how to rectify the dataframes and proceed further ?

Comment: @K.S what dataframe are you trying to get `sum_case` and `sum_ctrl` from? It doesn't look like `dataframe = pd.read_csv('final_out_transposed.csv')` is used anywhere

Comment: `final_out_transposed.csv` contains the transposed value, from which Im am calculating sum_case and sum_ctrl

Comment: but why are you defining `dataframe = pd.read_csv('final_out_transposed.csv')` if you aren't using it?

Comment: @Ian Thompson Now I understood why i was getting the error, because` final_out_transposed` does not have `sum_case and sum_ctrl`. I should use `sum.csv`. But im printing this file after the calculations. Please suggest the necessary edits in the code.

Comment: I have edited my code. Take a look and see if it works for you. Instead of `dataframe = pd.read_csv('final_out_transposed.csv')` I said `df = pd.read_csv('sum.csv')` and continued on from there.

Comment: @IanThompson With `sum.csv` im not getting any error but the columns are empty no values.

Comment: @IanThompson I am getting the values for T test NaN

Comment: @K.S please update your code above so I can what you are doing.

Comment: @IanThompson I have edited the question for entire code. `I am getting Nan`. I have used sum.csv

Comment: @K.S where is it returning `NaN`? The code you have displayed would still return errors at `(t_stat, p) = ttest_ind(df2['control'], df1['case'])` so I don't think you actually updated your code. Delete the code you don't need and replace it with the code that works up to the point of your problem.

Comment: @IanThompson Sorry Ian the edit was not right. I have done it and still the problem persists. `runfile('C:/IBD Bioproject/New folder/temp_3251.py', wdir='C:/IBD Bioproject/New folder')
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan`

Comment: @K.S can you show what `df.head()` looks like after you define `df = pd.read_csv('sum.csv')`?

Comment: @IanThompson                                                                                                        `df.head
Out[47]: 
<bound method NDFrame.head of         SRA ID            ERR169499            ERR169500            ERR169501  \
0        Label                    1                    1                    1   
1        TaxID  PRJEB3251_ERR169499  PRJEB3251_ERR169500  PRJEB3251_ERR169501   
2     333046.0                 0.05                  0.0                  0.0   
3       1049.0                 0.03                  0.0                  0.0  `

Comment: @K.S please put that in the question just below your current *working* code; not in the comments as it formats it weird.

Comment: @IanThompson sorry for that, done the edit in the question

Comment: @K.S why does that data look different than how you have it at the top of your problem? Is this from before you run the code or after?

Comment: @IanThompson its after running the code. The file sum.csv I have shown above is after writing all the calculation into it. I guess it is still taking final_out_transposed.

Comment: @IanThompson I am writing the file after all the calculations are done. But still it should take the column sum_case and sum+ctrl because those steps are done above t test.

Comment: @K.S so the `df.head()` that you just printed isn't from `'sum.csv'`? It looks like an exact copy of `'final_out_transposed.csv'` from the top of your question. Please fix this in your question.

Comment: @IanThompson But im reading `sum.csv` as the dataframe. So accordingly  df.head() should print that. Instead it is printing `final_out_transposed.csv`. That is where it is going wrong I guess. but how is that possible.

Comment: @K.S open the file `'sum.csv'` and see what it looks like. If it looks wrong then your code is wrong before you define `df = pd.read_csv('sum.csv')`

Comment: @IanThompson the file `sum.csv` without the `df = pd.read_csv('sum.csv')` is giving me all the results. `sum_ctrl, sum_case, mean_case, mean_ctrl` , but with `df = pd.read_csv('sum.csv')` im getting the error `EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`

Comment: @K.S what do you mean "the file `'sum.csv'` without the `df = pd.read_csv('sum.csv')` is giving me all the results"?

Comment: @Ian Thomson.. sorry for the confusion. I mean the file sum.csv without reading it into dataframe and using ttest is giving all the results as I have shown in the code above. When im writing just `df = pd.read_csv` its giving the error empty dataframe : no columns to parse

Comment: Is there a way i can show you my entire code and the files its generating.

Comment: I suggest cleaning up the code you already have. I'll make some edits to get you started. As you run your code, post the output after the first piece that doesn't return what it should. Meaning check every line that returns something to make sure it returns the correct data/file/etc.

Comment: @IanThompson Hi Ian, sorry for the late reply. I have made changes to my code. Im adding the ttest  and rank sum test after writing the file `sum.csv`. Now it is working fine. I guess i need to iterate it over the dataframe. Any suggestions with that ? I have made the changes for the new code in my question. Kindly go through it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164044/discussion-between-ian-thompson-and-k-s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for I think:

```
# assuming this data is coming from 'sum.csv'
'''
TaxID    sum_case   sum_ctrl  mean_case  mean_ctrl  n_case  n_ctrl
333046   4.76       4.56      xx.xx      xx.xx      xx      xx
1049     45.21      33.22     xx.xx      xx.xx      xx      xx
337090   35.98      16.71     xx.xx      xx.xx      xx      xx  
'''

import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

# read in data from 'sum.csv'
df = pd.read_csv('sum.csv')

df.head()
```

[image: df]

```
# run ttest using 'sum_ctrl' and 'sum_case' from 'sum.csv' data
ttest_ind(df.sum_ctrl, df.sum_case)
```

[image: results]

Comment: Im stuck with a problem, I guess I need to change few things. As Im taking the dataframe from `final_out_transposed` which does not contain the column sum_ctrl. Im getting the error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sum_case'`. im doing all the caluculation and writing it in `sum.csv`. Kindly help me with this. Also i cannot write it into `final_out_transposed` cause its structure is kind of complicated.I have edited the question for the code.

Comment: I will need to see what your data looks like for `'final_out_transposed.csv'` for me to help with that. What data did you use in your sample?